# If $A$ and $B$ are invertible matrices, is $A+B$ also an invertible matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The answer is obviously false in general, for example

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 2 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\
 \end{pmatrix}
, \ B=\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 2 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{2} \\
 \end{pmatrix}
, \ A+B=\begin{pmatrix}
  2 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 4 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \end{pmatrix},$$

are matrices with $A$ and $B$ both invertible but $A+B$ not invertible, but I'm wondering if there is a better way to prove this other than providing a counterexample?

Comment: What is wrong with providing a counter example as proof?

Comment: You cannot prove something is not true. In your case, there are examples of matrices A and B that do sum up to an invertible matrix. It's just not the case for all invertible matrices.

Comment: One can prove this with better example for $1\times 1$ matrices. Matrices $1$ and $-1$ are invertible but $1+(-1)=0$ is not.

Comment: The most direct way to *prove* that an assertion is false is to provide a counterexample. So what you have given is indeed a perfectly good proof.

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for a simpler counter example, here is a counter example for every size.

Let $A=I_n$ and $B=-I_n$, they are their own inverse. but $A+B$ is not invertible.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a necessary and sufficient condition for invertibility of $A+B$ provided that both $A,B$ are invertible:

> Let $A,B$ be two invertible matrices. Then $$A+B\text{ is invertible} \iff -1 \text{ is not an eigenvalue of } A^{-1}B.$$

*Proof*

$( \Leftarrow )$ Suppose that $A+B$ is not invertible. Then there exists $v \ne 0$ such that $$(A+B)v=0.$$

Distributing we get $Av + Bv = 0$, and then mulitplying by $A^{-1}$ we get $v + A^{-1}Bv = 0$.

Therefore, $(I + A^{-1}B)v=0$, and so $-1$ is an eigenvalue of $A^{-1}B$.

$(\Rightarrow)$ Instead suppose that $-1$ is an eigenvalue of $A^{-1}B$. Then $(I + A^{-1}B)v=0$, and by running the above argument backwards we get $A+B$ is not invertible.

$\hspace{16.5cm} \square$

Answer (score 0):

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field, and let $\mathrm{GL}(n)$ denote the set of invertible $n \times n$ matrices with entries in $\mathbb{F}$.

The statements

$$\neg \left[ \ \forall A,B \in \mathrm{GL}(n) \ \ A + B \in \mathrm{GL}(n) \ \right] $$

and

$$ \exists A,B \in \mathrm{GL}(n) \  \text{such that} \ A +B \notin \mathrm{GL}(n) $$

are equivalent.

So proving one is exactly the same as proving the other, and I can't think of a quicker or nicer way to prove the second statement than giving an example of such $A,B \in \mathrm{GL}(n)$.